# Macport skip dependency

Tags: macports

Is it possible to install a port also if a dependency fails to build?

I mean, I have to install texlive and it requires a lot of dependency and one on those (py26-libxml2) fails to build. Is there a way to skip it?

I know that it is no safe, but I need it and I don't want to install tex with MacTex.

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: I'd like to do this too. I'm trying to build kdelibs4 but the dep tree includes grantlee which is only needed to generate documentation.

Comment: This was fantastic to deal with the bug in py27-pil; requiring py27-tkinter to build stuff like py27-spyder; without actually needed the dep.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note before starting:** removing the dependency may break the build, so be prepared to do troubleshooting. There's no guarantee of success of course. Google may help with build errors, but that will only go so far. Perhaps you should try to figure out why py26-libxml2 is failing first.

**Editing dependencies**

Looks like you can edit the dependency list. The catch is that you already have to know what depends on py26-libxml2. You could use

```
port rdeps texlive
```

to see a basic tree, but each port will only appear once unless you use --full, which takes forever for texlive.

Once you've located the dependent, you can change its dependencies locally via the downloaded Portfile.

```
sudo port edit PORTNAME
```

You should then remove the dependency from depends_lib or depends_lib-append. I don't know much about the format so...

You should back up this file before editing. Its location is found via

```
port file PORTNAME
```

After editing, you can run rdeps again to see if any other dependency uses the one you want to omit.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can install a port variant without the unwanted dependency.

For example, let's say we're looking to install `libsdl2_image` without the whole `x11`.

`port deps libsdl2_image` and further `port deps ...` reveal that it's `libgif` that depends on `x11` and has a `+x11` (and `-x11`, which is more important!) variant.

`sudo port install giflib -x11` didn't immediately help, but yielded:

`Error: Please use the same variants again, or run 'port clean giflib' first to remove the existing partially completed build.`

Next,

```
sudo port clean giflib
sudo port install giflib -x11
```

did it: now `sudo port install libsdl2_image` doesn't install `x11`.

[And last](https://lists.macports.org/pipermail/macports-users/2008-May/010221.html) but not the least:

> From: Ryan Schmidt:
>
> If there's a wrong dependency in a port (or any other error in a port), we want the error reported to the maintainer and/or a bug created in the issue tracker so that it can be fixed.